# In what ways (other than color) does black Aluminum Oxide differ from white?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I work in a (physics) lab in which an aluminum oxide coating is applied to the inner surface of a plasma confinement vessel (made of Cu) to provide an electrically insulating layer that can withstand high temperature environments. The product we use comes in a medium that allows it to be brushed or sprayed onto the metal surface (something like: http://www.zypcoatings.com/aluminum-oxide-coatings/  -- see the data sheets).

I'm wondering if a similar product might exist for black aluminum oxide. I've seen that black aluminum oxide powder exists, but cannot find information on a coating product that is black.

I'd like to understand what the difference is between the two: Does black aluminum oxide have the same physical properties as the white variant? Is it reasonable to expect that a similar suspension or solution of black aluminum oxide in water or a different solvent could be made? What makes one black and the other white? Any information on their differences would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: The aluminium oxide that appears black seems that way because of the small particle size; the very small powder size promotes lots of light scattering. I would think that suspending fine particles would be easier than larger ones, it just might not be cost effective to use the very fine powder to make the coating solution for commercial sale vs custom order.